# Polars scan_ndjson does not work with streaming?

Tags: python-polars

I am attempting to read data from a large (300GB) newline-delimited JSON file, extract specific fields of interest and write them to a parquet file.  This question is a follow-up on [my previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78104587/polars-efficiently-extract-subset-of-fields-from-array-of-json-objects-list-of) which has more background and the structure of the data I'm working with.

Each line/JSON object is independent of the others, so I would have imagined this could be handled in a streaming fashion, processing the file (which is too large to fit in memory) in chunks.

The code that does the actual scan, collect and write is very simple:

```py
# define the schema...

pl.scan_ndjson(
        'data/input/myjson.jsonl',
        schema=prschema)\
    .collect(streaming=True)\
    .write_parquet('data/output/myparquet.parquet',
        compression='snappy',
        use_pyarrow=True
)
```

However, as I work with increasingly larger subsets of my final file, I see that memory consumption increases linearly with input file size.

If I check the explain plan using `explain(streaming=True)` I see that streaming is NOT being used:

```
Anonymous SCAN 
  PROJECT */6 COLUMNS
```

So my question is, why does streaming not appear to work for this seemingly straightforward read/write use case?

---

**UPDATED**

Using `sink_parquet` instead of `write_parquet` does not work (in fact it's what I had originally tried). To be sure that it wasn't due to the complex nature of my JSON files, I even tried a very simplified version that just attempts to write two scalar (no nested objects) fields:

```py
pl.scan_ndjson('data/input/myjson.jsonl')\
    .select('id', 'standing')\
    .sink_parquet(
        'data/output/myparquet.parquet',
        compression='snappy'
    )
```

This throws `InvalidOperationError: sink_Parquet(ParquetWriteOptions { compression: Snappy, statistics: false, row_group_size: None, data_pagesize_limit: None, maintain_order: true }) not yet supported in standard engine. Use 'collect().write_parquet()'`

Comment: Issue for `scan_ndjson` being incompatible with `sink_parquet`: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/10964

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Streaming only means that the input is pulled in batches. This is useful if you're doing something like a filter or aggregation, where it's possible to compute results without having all of the data in memory ahead of time. But the result of collecting is still a DataFrame that resides entirely in memory.

I believe what you want is `sink_parquet`, which is the lazy version of `write_parquet`.

```py
pl.scan_ndjson(...).sink_parquet(...)
```

Comment: unfortunately `sink_parquet` does not work, I've updated my original question with additional info.  From my reading of the documentation for `collect` (https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/lazyframe/api/polars.LazyFrame.collect.html), specifying `streaming=True` should result in `collect` processing the data in batches: "Process the query in batches to handle larger-than-memory data. If set to False (default), the entire query is processed in a single batch."

Comment: Yes, that refers to how the *input* is pulled in. The *output* is always an in-memory DataFrame. `streaming` does not affect the result of `collect()`, only how it operates under the hood.

Comment: Ah, I see.  So `collect(streaming=True)` is only useful for the case where input is larger than memory, but we're performing some processing (as you say, filtering, aggregation, whatever) which results in output being able to fit in memory.
From https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/10964#issuecomment-1709677796 it looks like maybe the underlying issue is that `scan_ndjson` doesn't yet have a streaming reader implemented yet.

Comment: It seems `sink_parquet` cannot be used with `scan_ndjson`: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/10964 :-(